# How do i kill off the termite inside the wood beam indoor?

Tags: pest-control, insect

How do i kill off the termite inside the wood beam indoor as a effective way?

After quite a long while to search youtube i don't find anything useful and hopefully the answer will be just to spray termidor or Demaon Max or other chemical treatment pesticide onto the wood beam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want a professional to treat the infestation and rather eradicate them yourself you risk not killing the whole colony. If the beam to be treated is still sound and not damaged you should treat it by Drilling several 1/4 inch holes, applying any liquid termite repellent made for wood into the holes until they are full.

Comment: @Victor- I've treated small localized infestations using this method. By small I mean areas smaller than a couple of feet and on non-bearing framing members. But after marking out the compromised section and boring into the wood I injected a product called "Termin-8" ;sold at most lumber and building yards. A turkey baster will suffice if you can't find a hypodermic syringe. Fill the holes to overflowing and wait until the wood absorbs and is saturated by it. Than re-fill. If you clean the "frass" (?) (termite droppings) from around the area you can see if you killed them by if more return.

Answer (score 2):

Don't delay. Termites can do a lot of damage. I would get them professionally taken care of.

Comment: I had no money, so i had to do that all by myself... Please help

Comment: Trying to do it yourself, and getting it wrong, may be more expensive than hiring a pro and still not solve the problem. Good luck...